# Yesod - include widget directly in template

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a scaffolded Yesod app and created a simple widget that looks like this and is located in separate module:

```
module Widget.Header where

import Prelude
import Yesod

twitterWidget :: MonadWidget m => String -> m ()
twitterWidget twitteruser = do
   toWidgetBody([hamlet| <a href="https://twitter.com/#{twitteruser}" .twitter-follow-button data-show-count="false">Follow @#{twitteruser}
                            <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
                       |])
```

I have included this module to .cabal file and I can load it in a Handler and all works.

```
twitterUsername :: String
twitterUsername = "someusername"

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    let submission = Nothing :: Maybe FileForm
        handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
    defaultLayout $ do
        let (commentFormId, commentTextareaId, commentListId) = commentIds
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Some title"
        twitterWidget twitterUsername 
        $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

So what I would like to do is to use it directly in another template but when I try do:

```
^{twitterWidget twitterUsername}
```

I get

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘m1’ arising from a use of ‘toWidget’
      prevents the constraint ‘(ToWidget App (m1 ()))’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘m1’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (site' ~ site, IO ~ m, a ~ ()) =>
                 ToWidget site' (WidgetT site m a)
          -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘(GHC.Base..)’, namely ‘toWidget’
      In the expression: asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget) (twitterWidget twitterUsername)
```

So my question is what is the right way to accomplish having multiple widgets loaded in templates all around the website serving different purposes ?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your template?

Comment: The template for this page is separated on header widget and home page. Header widget is loaded on each page in Foundation.hs and home page template contains only html so I guess it is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your

```
module Widget.Header where

import Prelude
import Yesod

twitterWidget :: MonadWidget m => String -> m ()
twitterWidget twitteruser = do
   toWidgetBody([hamlet| <a href="https://twitter.com/#{twitteruser}" .twitter-follow-button data-show-count="false">Follow @#{twitteruser}
                        <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
                   |])
```

to something more like

```
module Widget.Header where

import Import

twitterWidget :: Yesod site => String -> WidgetT site IO ()
twitterWidget twitteruser = do
   toWidgetBody([hamlet| <a href="https://twitter.com/#{twitteruser}" .twitter-follow-button data-show-count="false">Follow @#{twitteruser}
                        <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
                   |])
```

that way `m` becomes definitely `IO` and Haskell doesn't have to figure it out.